# Having some issues with Perl Splitting and Merging Functions

Tags: linux, perl, merge, split

First and foremost, I'm not familiar with Perl at all.  I've been studying C++ primarily for the last 1/2 year.  I'm in a class now that that is teaching Linux commands, and we have short little topics on languages used in Linux, including Perl, which is totally throwing me for a loop (no pun intended).  I have a text file that contains a bunch of random numbers separated by spaces and tabs, maybe even newlines, that gets read into the program via a filehandle.  I'm supposed to write 2 lines of code that split the lines of numbers and merge them into one array, inside of a foreach loop.  I'm not looking for an answer, just a nudge in the right direction.  I've been trying different things for multiple hours and feel totally silly I can't get it, I'm totally lost with the syntax.  Its just a bit odd not working inside a compiler and out of my comfort zone working outside of C++.  I really appreciate it.  I've included a few photos.  Basically, the code we are writing it just to store the numbers and the rest of the program will determine the smallest number and sum of all numbers.  Mine is currently incorrect because I'm not sure what to do.  In the output photo, it will display all the numbers being entered in via the text file, so you can see them.

[image: code]

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things to fix here. First of all, please don't post screenshots of your sample data or code, as it makes it impossible to copy and paste to test your code or data. Post your code/data by indenting it with four spaces and a newline preceding the code block.

Add `use strict;` in your script. This should be lesson 0 in your class. After that add `my` to all variable declarations.

To populate `@all_numbers` with contents of each line's numbers, without using `push`, you can use something like this:

```
foreach my $line (@output_lines)
{
    my @numbers = split /\s/, $line;
    @all_numbers = (@all_numbers, @numbers);
}
```

Comment: I realize it was very inconvenient.  I only posted photos of my code, versus the code, to keep it from being searchable.  Not sure how far my professors look into stack overflow, if at all.  None of them have ever mentioned not using help from a community, though.  Thats my only reason.  Secondly, the class is huge in what it goes over, but we don't spend considerable time on any one topic.  For example, we are only spending 4 hours on Perl in lecture, versus my two semesters already dedicated to just C++.  Thanks, I think this is really close to what is wanted.

Comment: I just wasn't sure how to notate the second merge line, thanks a ton.

Comment: This was exactly it.  100 percent.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Nothing wrong in taking help from community unless you are asking for full code without trying anything.

Comment: @Raju I do my best to never ask for full help on any problem.  In my previous posts with C++, I only ask for nudges on small portions of a problem I might be stuck on.  I'm pretty stubborn about learning it all on my own, because I truly care to learn this field, but sometimes you bang your head against the wall too much for so many hours, a tip from someone more intelligent is all you need.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @joe_04_04 ou can also always rename stuff and keep it abstract.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you need to store the all splitting element into array, so you looking for `push` function.

```
foreach $line (@input_lines)
{
    push(@all_numbers,split(/\s/,$line));

}
```

Your problem is, in every iteration, the splitted  value is over written in an array not to append together. For example,

```
@array = qw(one two three);
@array = qw(five four seven); 
print "@array";
```

output is `five four seven` not the `one two three five four seven` because this is reinitialize with a new values. You want to append the new values in the array in before or after use `unshift` or `push` 
for example

```
@array = qw(one two three);
push(@array,qw(five four seven));
```

Comment: In your first code block, I think you have a small typo and meant to split on `$line` instead of `$_`

Comment: I hated to "nit" about it, but OP is at the stage where he [probably] needs the precision in the examples. Also, so far, you're the only one doing the `push` which is the cleanest/fastest way [although sferncik _did_ do as much by linking to the doc for it]

Answer (score 4):

You say you're "not looking for an answer," so here's your nudge:

You're almost there. You split each line well (using `split/\s/`) and store the numeric values in `@all_numbers`. However, notice that each time around in the loop, you replace (using the assignment, `@all_numbers = ...`) the whole contents of `@all_numbers` with the numbers you found in the current line. Effectively, you're throwing away everything you've stored from the previous lines.

Instead, you want to *add* to `@all_numbers`, not replace `@all_numbers`. Have a look at the [push() function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) for how to do this.

NB: Your `split()` call is fine, but it's more customary to use `split(' ', $line)` in this case. (See [split()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html): you can use a single space, `' '`, instead of the pattern, `/\s/`, when you want to split on any whitespace.)

Comment: Looking at my output, I realized that the output was just the last line and I sort of figured that I was overwriting it, but I didn't know how to access each element of the array.  In C++, we would just the for the loop increment or decrement counter in the subscript of the array to access each new element, but I had no idea how to do that here.  I'll take a look into the push function, but it may be out of the scope of the lesson were learning, so I may have to find an alternative.

Comment: I'm almost certain they want you to get familiar with `push()` here, and use it. It's at the heart of the Perl language. And it's trivial to use, too; don't shy away from it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
my @all_numbers = map { split ' ', $_ } @output_lines;
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html